# Is there Anything Close to a Position: Relative-Fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site, **elemovements.com**, where, on the home page, you can click to view an archive of the news and a little popout appears.  I have taken advantage of jQuery Waypoints so that, when scrolling, the popout will follow you down the page.  Unfortunately, the way I have it set up, I have its position styled with CSS which works appropriately under the resolution I am using.  Unfortunately, not everyone uses 1600x900.  My question is (and I know there is no such thing in CSS): is there any way for an element to have *fixed* positioning *relative* to another element?  In my code, I created a JavaScript object which handles most of the operations for this archive popout called objArchive, and in it, a function called getRight() which I was attempting to use to remedy this situation whenever a person scrolled or resized under suitable conditions.  Alas, I could not get it to work.  You can take a look at the site [here](http://www.elemovements.com) and a majority of the code for it [here](http://el.x10.mx/js/scripts.js).  Whoever can help, I will definitely give you some credit in the code comments :)

By the way, to open it, look at the right hand side of the title bar for the "Latest News" box and there will be an "Archive" link.  Thanks!

Comment: So, the little "Archive" popout is the issue?

Comment: Not exactly.  The issue has been fixed, however.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an element `fixed` it positions it relative to the browser window, and only the browser window. However, since your website is centered, you have the center of the window as a constant and can position it relative to that center line. If you give your `.sticky` class these rules, you will have the position you're looking for.

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed !important;
  right: 50% !important;
  margin-right: -592px;
}
```

These rules positions the `.sticky` element so it's right edge is at the center line of the browser's width, then moves it 592 pixels to the right (which is half of you're containers width + the width of the element).

Comment: I knew about the relative to the browser window thing yet I still don't know why I didn't see this solution; it's so simple.  Thank you so much!  You're a keen one.